# Can Pickle remove files as well as create them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have only recently learnt how to use the Pickle module of Python, and I was wondering about the following: Pickle can create and read files if used via Python, but can it also delete them? I only want to delete the Pickle files, so that it stops clogging up my source folder, and up until now I have been having to do so manually. Can I write lines of code to do so automatically?

Answer (score 3):

`pickle` does not create files itself, it uses a file handle you provide (by using `open` or otherwise). If you want to manipulate the filesystem through Python, you can do so with [`os`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) and [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html).